# C++ copy constructors and assignments in cloneable hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, cloning

There is well-known `clone` idiom for copying `Derived` objects via pointer to `Base` class.

```
class Base{
  int b;
public: 
  virtual unique_ptr<Base> clone() const = 0;
  virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  int d;
public:
  virtual unique_ptr<Base> clone() const override {
    return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this);
  }
}
```

However, I can't find clear instructions how to define copy constructors and assignments in this case. This is how I suppose it should be done in `Base` class:

```
class Base {
protected:
  Base(const Base&) = default;
private:
  Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;
}
```

Is it necessary (in order to avoid potential slices)? Is it right way to do it?  Does it suffice or should I add such declarations to `Derived` class as well?

Comment: If your dealing with pointers to the objects you'll never you the assignment or copy constructor.

Comment: It depends on your current use case. If you want to allow only cloning - or cloning and copying are both acceptable. For allowing cloning and copying - do not bother about that stuff at all. For disallowing copying - delete your assignment and make your copy constructors protected  - like you showed.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. @Piotr, in my case does copy constructor in derived class become protected automatically?

Answer (score 0):

As derived classes use the copy constructor to create clones, you may like to make the copy constructors non-public to avoid accidental slicing but accessible to derived classes.

`protected` fills this requirement. It needs to be applied to each class' copy constructor because the compiler-generated copy constructor is `public`. It also makes sense to apply the same treatment to the assignment operator.

That also prevents `std::make_unique` from accessing the copy constructor though:

```
class A
{
protected:
    A(A const&) = default;
    A& operator=(A const&) = default;
public:
    A();
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    B(B const&) = default;
    B& operator=(B const&) = default;
public:
    B();

    std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const override { 
        return std::unique_ptr<A>(new B(*this)); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Is it enough to make protected only the base class copy constructor?

Comment: `protected` needs to be applied to each class' copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the copy assignment operator is probably a good idea, unless you need it.

Deleting `operator=(const Base&)` in `Base` is enough, as the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted for a derived class if the base class has no copy assignment operator (see  [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)).

If you really want copy assignment you can make the copy assignment operator virtual, and carefully implement the correct behaviour in the derived classes by

1. calling `Base::operator=` to assign the Base class members, and
2. assigning the members of the derived class, using `dynamic_cast` to ensure that the argument is of the correct type .

If done correctly, this avoids object slicing and retains the correct type.

An example (with copy constructor details omitted):

```
  struct Point {
    virtual Point& operator=(const Point& p) =default;
    int x;
    int y;
  };  

  struct Point3d :public Point{
    virtual Point3d& operator=(const Point& p);
    int z;
  };

  Point3d& Point3d::operator=(const Point& p)
  {
    Point::operator=(p);
    auto p3d = dynamic_cast<const Point3d*>(&p);
    if(p3d){
      z = p3d->z; 
    } else {
      z = 0;
    }
    return *this;
  }
```